# ASP.NET MVC 2 blog post seems to discuss nonexistent attributes

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, attributes, blogs

Reading [this Brad Wilson blog post](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2009/10/aspnet-mvc-2-templates-part-2-modelmetadata.html), I'm coming across several attributes (e.g., `DisplayFormatString`, `EditFormatString`, `ShortDisplayName`, `SimpleDisplayText`) that seem to have no available documentation, and I'm having no luck figuring out what namespace they belong to.

Do these attributes even exist? Have they been replaced by different attributes? What's going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there are attributes for these fields. That list is a list of properties found on ModelMetadata, and my guess is the default Data Annotations metadata provider doesn't populate those. You can build some custom attributes, and a custom metadata provider without to much fuss or muss. You can also populate that field from procedural code anywhere you have the ViewData instance.

Comment: Oh, you're right. I needed to look at the list at the bottom. That's where the attributes are. Thanks.